# Как протестировать, что метод create у контроллера MVC выполнился корректно?

Tags: java, mvc, testng

При интеграционном тестировании MVC как более правильно проверить корректность контроллера? Например, при создании сущности. Я так понимаю недостаточно получить ответ "Ок" сервиса. Как именно сделать проверку, что были изменения в базе данных? Сделать запрос к тому же контроллеру по id и свериться с полученными полями? Или напрямую к БД обратиться через репозиторий? Какие есть лучшие практики в подобных тестах?

Comment: Вызвать обратный метод GET /<entity_name>/{id} и проверить, что нужный элемент найден и содержит ожидаемые значения в полях.
Но это не гарантирует факта записи. Запись может состоятся отложено, а текущее значение берется из кеша 2го уровня.

Comment: Если ваше API предоставляет метод, чтобы получить сущность по id, можно его использовать. Если такого метода нет, тогда напрямую к базе можно обратиться.